# Haskell program crashing - infinite recursion? wrong where statement?

Tags: haskell, recursion, where-clause

I need to calculate the product of all factorials from 1..n. 
When I call this function double_factorial (with at least 2 or 3 as args), 
it seems to be called for a moment, but nothing happens, and after a few seconds the GHCi just closes. What is wrong? Is there some infinite recursion that I can't see? 
Here is my code :

```
double_factorial :: Integer->Integer
double_factorial n 
    | n<0 = error "negative number is given"
    | n==0 = 1
    | otherwise = (factorial n)*(double_factorial n-1)
    where
    factorial :: Integer->Integer
    factorial n 
        | n == 0  = 1
        | otherwise = n*(factorial n-1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(double_factorial n-1)` means `((double_factorial n) - 1)` so yes, it's an infinite recursion problem.

Answer (score 6):

First off, because you opened GHCi directly, the terminal window in which it is running closes as soon as GHCi stops running. If you open up `cmd` (or similar terminal) and then use GHCi from there, you can see the error that GHCi throws as it stops running. In this case we get:

```
<interactive>: out of memory
```

This does suggest an infinite recursion problem, as you already suspected.

Because `factorial` is the simpler function, it's easier to check if its recursive call is the culprit. It is, as `factorial n - 1` means `(factorial n) - 1` and not `factorial (n - 1)`. And calling `factorial n` in the definition of `factorial n` is pretty much the textbook case of infinite recursion. In `double_factorial` we see the same problem.

Comment: Why isn't that as a comment if this is not an answer?

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac: I can't actually comment yet. I saw your answer as I was typing mine, so I figured I shouldn't repeat it. But I also thought this was useful information anyway and I had already typed it. This was probably a rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: My bad, I should have observed that you cannot comment. Anyway, you can turn this into an answer and you'll get some upvotes (allowing you to comment at a later point :) )

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac: I've edited the post to also include the answer to the question. Ironically, now I have enough upvotes that I can make it into a comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

You have a recursion problem: `f x - 1` is not the same as `f (x - 1)`. Solution (removing unneeded parentheses and adding the needed ones):

```
double_factorial :: Integer->Integer
double_factorial n 
    | n<0 = error "negative number is given"
    | n==0 = 1
    | otherwise = factorial n * double_factorial (n-1)
    where
    factorial :: Integer->Integer
    factorial n 
        | n == 0  = 1
        | otherwise = n * factorial (n-1)
```